# How to install and configure sendmail for php

Tags: apache2, php, mail

I am running LAMP on my Ubuntu 10.04 Desktop linux and using it as a development machine.

I need to send emails from my php pages, but it seems that the sendmail php command needs sendmail installed on the laptop.

I understand I can install sendmail by `sudo aptitude install sendmail`, but don't know how to configure it as after installing it and restarting apache2, sendmail from php still does not work and returns no errors at all.

I am assuming sendmail needs to be configured after installing it, before it can be used in php.

Therefore, my question is, how do I install and configure sendmail on ubuntu 10.04 so I can use sendmail via cli at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this will help help http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/doc8.12/op.html

I haven't tried sendmail, i use postfix.

Comment: why use postfix over sendmail?  can I send emails from php using postfix?  would it be easier to install and configure postfix?

Comment: yes, its very easy.